# Regex end with same pattern select

Tags: java, regex

I have two string of pattern like below :

```
 1. com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.motor.2f628568b15f11eb85290242ac130003
 2. com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.2f628568b15f11eb85290242ac130003
```

The generic format is **com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.< STRING >.< UUID >**  and **com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.< UUID >**

I am using regex = `^com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.*`

It is selecting both, but I want to select the 2nd string only com.sumeet.iot.op.v1.< UUID >

What will be regex to select only the second string?

Comment: ^com\.sumeet\.iot\.op\.v1\.[a-z0-9]+$

Comment: In regex, `.` means *any character* (optionally except the newline), not a period.  
To denote a period, you have to escape it like `\.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```regex
^com\.sumeet\.iot\.op\.v1\.[a-f0-9]{32}$
```

The `[a-f0-9]{32}$` final portion of the regex ensures that the second variant of the domain which you want to match ends in a UUID.

Comment: Since the `UUID` is in hex, `[0-9a-f]` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You could be lenient and do `^com\.sumeet\.iot\.op\.v1\.[^.]+$`